# Magento - Add customer attribute to order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, orders, grid, backend

I'm trying to add a custom customer attribute to the order grid. This custom attribute borns from an extension that I had installed on magento. This special field i managed to get it in customer grid by entering this code in the Grid.php of the customer list:

```
$this->addColumn('agente', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Agente'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'agente',
        ));
```

But in the Grid.php of the orders does not work and I tried everything.
The last code that I tried is this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'sfoa.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfoa.email'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('agente', array(
            'header' => 'Agente',
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'agente',
        'filter_index' => 'sfoa.agente'));
```

The error that returns me in the log is always this: "Unknown column 'sfoa.agente' in 'field list', query was: SELECT`main_table`. *, `Sfoa`.`agente` FROM`sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`"

How else could I take this attribute and insert it into Order Grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`agente` is a customer attribute : so you have to join the `sales_flat_order` table (which is the main table of the order grid collection) and the table where the data of your attribute are stored.
You should be able to use the `customer_id` to join the two tables.

So, could you try this :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $agenteAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'agente');
    $agenteTable = $agenteAttribute->getBackendTable();
    $agenteId = $agenteAttribute->getAttributeId();

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('ca' => $agenteTable),
        'ca.attribute_id='.$agenteId.' AND ca.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
        array('agente'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('ca.value')
        )
    );


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
   $this->addColumn('agente', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('agente'),
        'index' => 'agente',
    ));

}
```

Comment: Great man!!! Thank you very much! :D One more thing please: To add a default filter to loading the order page how could I do? The code I would like to use for the filter is this:
->addFieldToFilter('agente',array('in' => array(312)))
In customer grid works but in order grid not works.

Comment: Error log that return for the filter of the field 'agente' is this: Unknown column 'agente' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`agente` IN(312))";i:1;s:5885:

Comment: I'm not sure how to set a default filter on your grid. Maybe you can try to add `$this->setDefaultFilter(array('agente'=>312)); ` in the `__construct()` method of your grid.

Comment: I tried man but the error log is the same: "Unknown column 'agente' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`agente` LIKE '%312%')";"

Comment: This error occurs to me because in the "search filter" table of the orders the customer attribute "agent" does not really exist but only in the table of the customer list at the moment. Do I have to create a table on the database for this or does a function exist that allows me to recall this filter?

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure that you don't have to modify the database : there should be a way to modify the select request in order to make the agente attribute available. Unfortunatly, I don't know how to do that. I looked for "default filter grid magento" here and there is a lot of similary question : I hope you will find your answer here. Or maybe you may have to ask an other question dealing with this specific case.

Comment: Excuse me man for this last question. Instead if I want to be able to show the attribute column "agent" in the invoice, shipment and orderitem grid I have to use the same code? Because if I try to replicate it in the other files grid.php tells me that the column "main_table.customer_id" is unknown

Comment: In our previous code, the main table was `sales_flat_order` in which there is a column `customer_id`. This is why we were able to join. This is not the case of the table `sales_flat_invoice` for example. This will be more difficult : `sales_flat_invoice` has the `order_id` column which you can use to join with the `sales_flat_order` table; then you will have to join again as we did.

Comment: Excellent thanks, in fact if I write "main_table.order_id" does not report an error. So then if I want to get the "agent" attribute in the invoice grid I will have to repeat another joinLeft () and link it to the customer table ?!

Comment: Yes that's it. Multiple join could be tricky (good luck) but this is the idea : use the commun column to join 2 tables and repeat the process.